# How to find the Literal and Link Button inside Repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt">
   <ItemTemplate>                    
        <asp:LinkButton ID="MyLink" runat="server" Text="Fair" ></asp:LinkButton>
          <span class="literal">
            (<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Lit1" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>'></asp:Literal>)
          </span>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see above I have a literal and Link button inside the Repeater. I want to get the value of the Literal on Link Button click.

I have used the given code to find the Link Button click:

```
$('#MyLink').click(function () {    
    alert($(this).attr('MyLink'));  
});
```

The above failed because of the Link button is inside the Repeater. Can anyone please update the code for my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Use `Class` instead of `Id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `class` to your `link` like,

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MyLink" class="MyLink" runat="server" Text="Fair" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){// write your code in document ready
     $('.MyLink').click(function () {    
          alert($(this).attr('Text'));
     });
});
```

**Updated,** If you want to get the `literal text` then add a `class literal` to your `literal element` like,

```
(<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Lit1" ClientIDMode="Static" class='literal' Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>'></asp:Literal>)
```

And change `jquery code` like,

```
$(function(){// write your code in document ready
     $('.MyLink').click(function () {    
          alert($(this).next('.literal').attr('Text'));
     });
});
```

Try it **after looking your `HTML`,**

```
$(function(){
    $('.clsMyLink') .click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).next('.literal').text());
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cWbz5/)

Comment: I have added a class clsMyLink, by this I am able to find the LinkButton, but in attr(), I have used the ID which shows undefined

Comment: `Inspect the element` and check in `console` that the `attributes` are applied to it or not.

Comment: you have posted your answer in which we are able to find to find the click event of Link Button, but I actually wants to find the Literal Text on Link Button Click

Comment: <a id="MainContent_rpt_MyLink_0" class="clsMyLink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$rpt$ctl00$MyLink','')">Fair</a>
The above I found by Inspect element

Comment: I don't think so we can add the "class" in Literal.

Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal' does not have a public property named 'class'.

Comment: Use a `label` or `span` instead of `literal`

Comment: Yes I just updated my question using span, but alert still shows undefined

Comment: <div>           
                               
                    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$rpt$ctl00$MyLink','')" class="clsMyLink" id="MainContent_rpt_MyLink_0">Fair</a>
                    <span class="literal">
                    (20)</span></div>

Comment: Finally get success.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

server control hase different Id in javascript. try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#<%= MyLink.ClientID %>').click(function () {    
     alert($(this).attr('MyLink'));  
  });
});
```